# C# udp Socket don't receive in long way connections ( vps to client )

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, receiver

I have an udp client server source on C# and now I have a problem: I test my source on localhost but it doesn't receive on long way connections for example a VPS to a client.

Client:

```
private static void StartListener()
{
        bool done = false;

        UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
        IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);

        try
        {
            while (!done)
            {
                byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
                Thread.Sleep(100);

                byte[] dcbufresponse = new byte[512];
                dcbufresponse = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0xc00901");
                IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipaddresssv), 9052);
                s.SendTo(dcbufresponse, dcbufresponse.Length, SocketFlags.None, ipep);
                done = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            listener.Close();
        }
    }
```

Server :

```
private static Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
private static IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipnow), 9052);
                                    s.SendTo(dcbuf, dcbuf.Length, SocketFlags.None, ipep);
                                    Console.WriteLine("sended");
                                    sended.Add(ipnow);
                                    try
                                    {
                                        listener.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
                                        byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
                                        string dcresponse = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                                        Console.WriteLine(dcresponse);
                                    }
```

Problem is this : client doesn't receive anything and client can not send to server after receiving ...

Edit :
My Serve Have Two Ip Address !
and i thinking that i must bind once of my two ip address to my udp client :-?
do you think that its work ?

Comment: Test the connection and network  routing using a network terminal program like HW-Group's 'Hercules'. Maybe the UDP routing itself fails and it has nothing to do with your program. Use Sysinternals TCPView to monitor connections. Both programs are basic tools in network troubleshooting.

Comment: VPS = Virtual private server

Comment: my vps network is good and work very fine with another apps and server files !

Comment: You can also use the mentioned apps to debug your own program.... 'Basic tools in network troubleshooting'. Isn't it your program having networking trouble?